# How to remove a tag link a href without removing the link text in Html Agility Pack?

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I have to replace the tag with HAP - HTML Agility Pack, in order to get a link without removing the link text. For e.g. in this case:

```
<p>This is <a href="mylink">the link</a></p>
```

I want to replace the link and the desired result should be:

```
<p>This is <span>the link<span></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this function, getting a html string as input.

```
public string CleanLinks(string input) {
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(input);
            var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
            if (links == null) return input;
            foreach (HtmlNode tb in links)
            {
                HtmlNode lbl = doc.CreateElement("span");
                lbl.InnerHtml = tb.InnerHtml;

                tb.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(lbl, tb);
            }

            return doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
        }
```